# Can you drop the "の方” in the AよりBのほうが... construction

Tags: usage, grammar

Can you drop the "の方” in the AよりBのほうが... construction? I'm asking because I heard this line in a song I was listening to:

> 野菜よりお肉が食べたい

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can drop it. Also, depending the context you can even ommit より and it will be understood.

For example, あっちの方が食べたい - I want to eat that over there (among others I want that one in particular).